# SQL Output Multiple Local Variables into one Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Is it possible, using SQL, to output multiple separately defined local variables into one column as separate rows? Eg.

```
DECLARE var1 INT = 4
DECLARE var2 INT = 5
DECLARE var3 INT = 6
```

And then select the variables in some manner like

```
SELECT (var1, var2, var3) AS UserIDs,
       ('u1', 'u2', 'u3') AS Names
```

Which would produce the following table:

```
UserIDs | Names
   4    |  u1
   5    |  u2
   6    |  u3
```

Comment: @MatBailie OP said SSMS, so SQL server is implied

Comment: @MatBailie a_horse_with_no_name has updated the tags

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Table valued constructor

```
SELECT *
FROM   (VALUES (@var1,'u1'),
               (@var2,'u2'),
               (@var3,'u3')) tc (UserIDs, Names)
```

Comment: That's a neat approach. I found more info [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2014/10/30/sql-server-beginning-table-valued-constructors-notes-from-the-field-052/)

Answer (score 4):

```
select var1 as UserID, 'u1' as Name
union all
select var2, 'u2'
union all
etc
etc
```

Comment: @PM77-1 Muchos gracias

Comment: This did the job however, I'm going to accept @Prdp's Answer

Comment: @Xynos to be fair, prdp's is a better answer